# Dbeaver restore unsaved script

Tags: restore, dbeaver

I am trying to restore an unsaved dBeaver script. I opened my DBeaver again after my system got shutdown abruptly and I can't find anything. All my SQL script are gone.

What can I do to restore or to find these script files?
In which folder are SQL scripts saved?

Answer (score 13):

You can find all your project scripts in DBeaver in the ["Projects"](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/wiki/Projects-View) tab in the "Scripts" folder.

Or try to check this path manually: AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspaceName\General(Project Name)\Scripts
(Some variables must be changed in this path)

Comment: This folder stores the saved scripts. Unable to find unsaved scripts.

Comment: It doesn't help at this point, but it's worth turning on Auto-save (Preferences/Editors/SQL Editors/Auto-save after any modifications) for this exact thing. Just saved my bacon.

Answer (score 5):

If you installed DBeaver with snap on Linux, check

```bash
~/snap/dbeaver-ce/198/.local/share/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/Scripts
```

*(change the number 198 or workspace6 to what you have)*

Mind that the .local is a hidden folder, you need to show hidden files if you just click there.

Then check whether you find some temporary files in there.

Comment: note: "~/.local/share/DBeaverData/workspace6/General/Scripts/Script.sql" is the default path if you installed dbeaver from the .deb package

Answer (score 3):

You can find it in `C:\Users\[your_user_name_enter_here]\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData\workspace6\General\Scripts` if the path yields an error, you can go on from `C:\Users\[your_user_name_enter_here]\AppData\Roaming\DBeaverData`. Otherwise, you can follow  the same way as seen below image.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since your scripts weren't saved on the disc, they are gone. Unfortunately, there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 2):

I have deleted a script by accident in DBeaver.
I've pressed Ctrl+Z on the left panel and the script appeared, but corrupted. So rigth click > Compare with > Local history
Then I could see previous versions. Hope this helps anyone. LOL
[Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nOLL.png)